# Getting a permission denied error when I have permission

Tags: java, excel, error-handling, io, conceptual

I'm writing an excel spreadsheet file (.xls) to a directory to which I have permission, xlsOutput is a directory I made at the root of my project with full permission (right click directory>properties>resource?rwx for all three groups (owner, group, other)

however I'm getting the flowing stack trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /xlsOutput (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
    at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:301)
    at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:286)
    at com.generalatomics.ctg.taxengine.automation.tools.testhelper.writers.ExcelTemplateWriter.write(ExcelTemplateWriter.java:33)
    at com.generalatomics.ctg.taxengine.automation.tools.testhelper.TestClasses.testXMLToXLS(TestClasses.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Not sure why I can't write to this directory? Am I missing something obvious? I feel like I am. Any help or assistance would be much appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

```
@Test
public void testXMLToXLS() throws Exception {
    ITemplateGenerator tGen = new CalcTemplateGenerator();
    TestTemplate template = tGen.generateTemplate("xmlDir");
    ITemplateWriter writer = new ExcelTemplateWriter();

    String file = "/xlsOutput";
    File f = new File(file);
    logger.debug("Can write: "+f.canWrite()); // returns false but why??
    writer.write(template, file);
}

public void write ( TestTemplate template , String path ) throws Exception {

    CellFormat formatHeaders = new WritableCellFormat( new WritableFont( WritableFont.createFont("Calibri"), 12,  WritableFont.BOLD ) );
    CellFormat formatText = new WritableCellFormat( new WritableFont( WritableFont.createFont("Calibri"), 12,  WritableFont.NO_BOLD ) );

    // Create workbook object at the specified path (output directory)
    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook( new File ( path));

    // Create a spreadhseet with name of topic and the index number at which to insert
    WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet( template.getTopic(), 0) ;
    ...etc
}
```

Edit:

Figured it out....

String file = "xlsOutput/testFile.xls";

I should not have included "/" in front of the directory...stupid mistake. Thanks everyone for helping

Comment: post some code, just posting the error is useless, show us how you're doing what you're trying to do

Comment: added some code, code is complex. Not sure if posting more would help, this error seems common. I think I'm missing something obvious

Comment: `/xlsOutput` means the file/folder called `xlsOutput` in your system's root directory. Not the root of your project.

Comment: call `canWrite` on the file (not directory) you're writing to

Comment: It returned false, but we already know this? That is my question, why is it false?

Comment: setWritale() to the file and try once. Look at java docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.htmlc

Comment: I made a silly mistake by including "/" @immibis thanks just saw ur comment

Answer (score 0):

You supplied an *absolute* file system path, `/xlsOutput`, one beginning with a `/`. If you were to omit the leading `/', the JRE would interpret that as being relative to the system property **user.home** which would likely be the directory your project. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

I made a silly mistake by including "/" @immibis thanks